# non blocking input in c

Tags: c++, c, fork

I want to implement a functionality such that a loop keeps on iterating and  simultaneously takes input from user if available.
I have implemented following code but the value of scanned variable "a" does not get reflected while printing.

```
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid == 0 )
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
else
{
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear...what happens in one process cannot affect the variables in the other process.  These are processes, not threads within a single process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you make fork(),the child process will get created with shared text region of program,but data and stack section of created child are different than parent,so child will always print a=1.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have two separate processes using fork(). You will need to use threads if you want to follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are getting two different processes, each one has it's own `a`.

You should use Linux [pipes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's faster if you use fcntl() to mark your stdin as non-blocking and then in the loop do what you need and also try to read, it will fail if no data is available and will store the data in the buffer if it was available. That will use 100% of your CPU tho. To check if data is available you should use select().

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shared memory, but you will have to synchronize the access to the shared memory segment by using semaphores.